# How do I implement login using passportjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I'm making a login page for my web app and I cant figure out how to get any user to properly login. I want when ever the user submits the form it will use post to then check mongoDB for the matching email and password and if its there to log them in and redirect to the next page.

```
//Passportjs stuff
const crypto = require('crypto');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:87887/members-only-proj', {
// useNewUrlParser: true,
// useUnifiedTopology: true
}, console.log("connected to database"));

const UsersModel = mongoose.model('Users', new mongoose.Schema({
// Define your data schema here
    email: { type: String, required: true},
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    admin: {type: Boolean}
// Add more fields as needed
}));

//Sign Up
    app.post("/sign-up.html", async (req, res, next) => {//Post needs to be the same as the file page location
        try {
                if (req.body.password != req.body.confirmPassword ) {
                    console.log("Password and Confirm Password do not match");
                    res.redirect("errorSignUp.html");
                    return;
            }
            const hashedPassword = await bcryptjs.hash(req.body.password, 13);
            const users = new UsersModel({
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hashedPassword,
                admin: false
            });
            const result = await users.save();
            res.redirect("log-in.html");
            console.log(result);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error");
            res.redirect("errorSignUp.html");
            return next(err);
            };
    });
// Log-in
app.post("/log-in",
   passport.authenticate("local", {
      successRedirect: "secret-pass.html",
      failureRedirect: "log-in.html"
  })
);

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
     function(email, password, done) {
       users.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
       }
        if (!users) {
          return done(null, false);
       }
        if (!users.verifyPassword(password)) {
          return done(null, false);
       }
          return done(null, users);
       });
    }
));
```

Comment: What error did you get? Explain your problem in more detail for us to be able to help you